# homebrew install - share/info are gone after installation?

Tags: macos, installation, homebrew

I wanted to install some info document of [libavl](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/avl). I found some weird behavior of [brew](http://brew.sh) command with the following brew library that I made. What I did were:

First, I compile it with "make libavl.info."
Second, I created share/info under brew KEG PREFIX.
Third, I installed some info files to that share/info.

I do not know yet how I can symbolic-link those info files in system directory such as "/usr/local/share/info", but I want to have this brew formula. To make sure before and after installing info files that I have those info files in the corresponding KEG PREFIX, I printed directory structure in a file called "log," which is also installed to the KEG PREFIX. But, those info files disappeared after the installation. I do not know what happened.  I do not know where I should ask in the homebrew website Brew.sh, so I ask this question here.

THIS IS THE FORMULA FILE called "avl.rb"

```
require 'formula'
class Avl < Formula
  homepage 'http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/avl'
  url 'ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/avl/avl-2.0.3.tar.gz'
  sha1 'ec2e025838c846fbc05fb60cf49035f2e97f37f3'

  def install
    system "make", "libavl.info"
    info.mkpath
    system "/usr/local/bin/tree " "#{prefix} > #{prefix}/log"
    info.install "libavl.info"
    info.install "libavl.info-1"
    info.install "libavl.info-2"
    info.install "libavl.info-3"
    info.install "libavl.info-4"
    system "/usr/local/bin/tree " "#{prefix} >> #{prefix}/log"
  end
end
```

The "log" file content before info.install command in the brew formula:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/avl/2.0.3
├── log
└── share
    └── info

2 directories, 1 file
```

This is the content of "log" file after info.install command:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/avl/2.0.3
├── log
└── share
    └── info
        ├── libavl.info
        ├── libavl.info-1
        ├── libavl.info-2
        ├── libavl.info-3
        └── libavl.info-4

2 directories, 6 files
```

This is the final installed KEG PREFIX directory. There is the "log" file, but no "share/info" directory in it.

```
/usr/local/Cellar/avl/2.0.3
├── AUTHORS
├── COPYING
├── ChangeLog
├── INSTALL_RECEIPT.json
├── NEWS
├── README
├── TODO
└── log

0 directories, 8 files
```

I will appreciate any answers to this mystery.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew does not install info files by default.  You can change this by setting `HOMEBREW_KEEP_INFO=1`.